# Properly delete duplicates in a list

Tags: java, list, duplicates

Given the following datatype `Testcase` (`XQuery`, `Testpath`, `FirstInputFile`, `SecondInputFile`, `Expected`)

how can I properly delete duplicates.

Definition of duplicates:

If `FirstInputFile` already in the list as `SecondInputFile` vice versa.

Here is the Testdata

```
tcs.add(new HeaderAndBodyTestcase("XQ 1", "/1", "FAIL", "FAIL2", "FAILED"));
    tcs.add(new HeaderAndBodyTestcase("XQ 1", "/1", "FAIL2", "FAIL", "FAILED"));
    tcs.add(new HeaderAndBodyTestcase("XQ 2", "/2", "FAIL4", "FAIL3", "FAILED2"));
    tcs.add(new HeaderAndBodyTestcase("XQ 2", "/2", "FAIL3", "FAIL4", "FAILED2"));
```

and here is the function

```
 protected void deleteExistingDuplicatesInArrayList(final ArrayList<HeaderAndBodyTestcase> list) {


    for (int idx = 0; idx < list.size() - 1; idx++) {

        if (list.get(idx).firstInputFile.equals(list.get(idx).secondInputFile)
                || (list.get(idx + 1).firstInputFile.equals(list.get(idx).firstInputFile)
                        && list.get(idx).secondInputFile.equals(list.get(idx + 1).secondInputFile)
                        || (list.get(idx).firstInputFile.equals(list.get(idx + 1).secondInputFile)
                                && list.get(idx).secondInputFile.equals(list.get(idx + 1).firstInputFile)))) {
            list.remove(idx);
        }

    }

}
```

This solution is already working, but seems very crappy, so is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Output= `new HeaderAndBodyTestcase("XQ 1", "/1", "FAIL", "FAIL2", "FAILED")` and `new HeaderAndBodyTestcase("XQ 2", "/2", "FAIL4", "FAIL3", "FAILED2")` (first and third)?

Comment: Your solution will only work if those duplicates are consecutive elements in your list (next to each other in the list). Is that allways the case or could there be a scenario where an element at index 4 is a duplicate of the element at index 1 for example?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your rather peculiar "equality" constraints, I think the best way would be to maintain two sets of already seen first- and second input files and a loop:

```
Set<String> first = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> second = new HashSet<>();
for (HeaderAndBodyTestcase tc : tcs) {
    if (! first.contains(tc.getSecondInputFile()) && 
            ! second.contains(tc.getFirstInputFile())) {
        first.add(tc.getFirstInputFile());
        second.add(tc.getSecondInputFile());
        System.out.println(tc); // or add to result list
    }
}
```

This will also work if "equal" elements do not appear right after each other in the original list.

Also note that removing elements from a list while iterating the same list, while working sometimes, will often yield unexpected results. Better create a new, filtered list, or if you have to remove, create an `Iterator` from that list and use it's `remove` method.

---

On closer inspections (yes, it took me that long to understand your code), the conditions in your current working code are in fact much different than what I understood from your question, namely:

- remove element if first and second is the same (actually never checked for the last element in the list)
- remove element if first is the same as first on last, *and* second the same as second on last
- remove if first is same as last second *and* vice versa
- only consider consecutive elements (from comments)

Given those constraints, the sets are not needed and also would not work properly considering that *both* the elements have to match (either 'straight' or 'crossed'). Instead you can use pretty much your code as-is, but I would still use an `Iterator` and keep track of the `last` element, and also split the different checks to make the whole code much easier to understand.

```
HeaderAndBodyTestcase last = null;
for (Iterator<HeaderAndBodyTestcase> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    HeaderAndBodyTestcase curr = iter.next();
    if (curr.firstInputFile.equals(curr.secondInputFile)) {
        iter.remove();
    }
    if (last != null) {
        boolean bothEqual = curr.firstInputFile.equals(last.firstInputFile) 
                         && curr.secondInputFile.equals(last.secondInputFile);
        boolean crossedEqual = curr.secondInputFile.equals(last.firstInputFile)
                            && curr.firstInputFile.equals(last.secondInputFile);
        if (bothEqual || crossedEqual) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    last = curr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

put everything in a `Set` using a comparator if necessary, and create a list from this set if you really need a List (and not a Collection)

```
Set<HeaderAndBodyTestcase> set = new Hashset<>(list);
```

Comment: To make it a list:  `new ArrayList(new Hashset<>(list);)`

Comment: How is a set going to work here, given OP's constraints?

Comment: @tobias_k once you have your set, you can build a list out of it, without any duplicate, so it's exactly what the OP is expecting, unless...?

Comment: OP defines duplicates as "If FirstInputFile already in the list as SecondInputFile vice versa." In particular, that means that A can be "equal" to B, and B to C, but A is not equal to C. How to do this with a `Set` and any implementation of `hashCode` and `equals`?